# SQL: how to alter column size

Tags: sql, ms-access, resize

What SQL statement will resize a column in an Access MDB database?

Comment: Read the manual for your RDBMS software. It's free and online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER columnname` is the command you want. Syntax may vary depending on your database system.

**Edit:** Ah Access. In that case, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177883(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Indeed it may vary, since this wouldn't work using SQL Server, but Oracle. =)

Comment: @Will I was leaning towards MySQL until the OP clarified the question

Answer (score 0):

Example for MySQL on how to change size of a column named baz in table bar in database foo to 20 characters.

```
ALTER TABLE `foo`.`bar` MODIFY COLUMN `baz` VARCHAR(20)
```

Check the SQL manual for the exact syntax for your database.

[MySQL ALTER manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

---

**Edit:** This is for MS ACCESS 2007:

```
ALTER TABLE Employees ALTER COLUMN Salary CHAR(20);
```

Got this example from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177883%28v=office.12%29.aspx)